# Передача объектов из двух контроллеров в таблицу

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios7

Расскажите (в теории), есть таббар, на нем два контроллера с картинками. Я на одном и другом выделяю картинки, потом на одном из них (любом) жму кнопку продолжить. Нужно с обоих таббаритемов передать объекты в общую таблицу.

Comment: По нажатию "продолжить" как будет выполняться переход? pushViewController в том же табе, где нажали на кнопку или как-то иначе?

Comment: Я уже решил задачу. Спасибо за отклик. Сделал через синглтон, как базу передаваемых объектов из двух контролеров.

Comment: @iSerg публикуйте свой ответ тогда :)